# Undelete deleted issue in Mantis?

Tags: bug-tracking, mantis

Is there a way to "Undelete" an issue which was deleted?

The developer thought it was a duplicate issue, but instead of closing it as "Duplicate" it was deleted. But the issues contains some "notes" which are useful.

Thanks.

Comment: noselasd Mantis is just a simple php issue tracking application. Server Fault is for server system administration isn't it? I don't think it belongs on serverfault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the Mantis code, I see some inserts on to a table called `mantis_bug_history_table` whenever a modification/deletion happens to bugs.

But unfortunately the bug text doesn't seem to be archived :|

Wthout a backup of the db it might be impossible to recover.

Another thing is you shouldn't have the delete option turned on in your Mantis workflow for anyone especially a developer.

You can change that by logging on to Mantis as admin. Then navigate to Manage -> Manage Configuration-> Workflow Thresholds, uncheck all roles for "Delete an Issue" and save your changes. This is for future reference.

Comment: I confirm that it is not possible to perform an undelete - once the record's been removed from the DB, it's gone for good (unless of course your RDBMS allows for recovery, or to restore from backups as previously suggested)